# Yum update was unable to get the latest packages from custom central repo

Tags: yum

we are having an instance (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS) which is using as a central repository (yum repo) and the build packages will be stored in this server. Earlier we were running the Jenkins pipeline to build and push the packages on to the server. Recently the pipeline is migrated to Azure DevOps and from here we can able to build and push the packages on to the server. But when we will run the yum update or yum install from other servers it's still refereeing to old package version which built from the Jenkins and not from the Azure pipeline. We tried by running the reposync command to sync it but it's still not syncing. Please someone help here to get the latest packages.

ran resynch command but no use with it